# How to use outwards

Tags: word-choice

I am look for the right word to teach some how to build a ball " from magnetic shapes" with only black sides facing the inside 
So can i say :
Creat a ball with keeping the black sides inwards and the colored sides facing the outwards?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example sentence

> Create a ball with keeping the black sides inwards and the colored sides facing the outwards?

you are basically correct, however more natural sounding might be either

> Create a ball *(by)* keeping the black sides *facing* inwards and the colored sides facing outwards.
>   Create a ball *(by)* keeping the black sides *inside* and the colored sides *outside*.